# How to use php include with js menu

Tags: php, javascript

I am putting together a website and it has a menu system set up in javascript. I dont want to have to update each and every page when the site changes.

I tried using php's `include` statement to handle that but it won't work. It wont even show basic data.

#### index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php include('nav.php');?>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
<!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css">
#menu li {
position:static;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->


<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="description" content="Your description goes here" />
<meta name="keywords" content="your,keywords,goes,here" />
<meta name="author" content="Your Name" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz|Droid+Sans|Princess+Sofia' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="inland-hembygd.css" />

<script src="menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.nivo.slider.js"></script>
<title>Through His Eyes Photography</title>
</head>
<link href="drop-down-menu.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    padding:20px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:62.5%;

}
#container {
    margin:50px auto;
    width:500px;
}
</style>

<!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css">

#menu li {
    position:static;
}

</style>
<![endif]-->
<body>


<div id="wrapper960" class="clearfix">












<div id="header" class="clearfix shadow">
<div id="sitetitle" class="clearfix">
<h1><a href="index.html">Through His Eyes Photography</a></h1>

<br /><br />

<!-- CONTAINER -->
<span id="container" >

<!-- NAVIGATION -->
<ul id="menu">

    <li><a href="index.php" title="Portraiture Gallery" class="selected">Portraiture Gallery</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="portraiture/adults.php" title="Adults">Adults  </a></li>
    <li><a href="portraiture/seniors.php" title="Seniors">Seniors  </a></li>
    <li><a href="portraiture/infantsandchildren.php" title="InfantsandChildren">Infants and Children  </a></li>
    <li><a href="portraiture/multiples.php" title="Multiples">Mutiples  </a></li>
    <li><a href="portraiture/hisangels.php" title="Hisangels">His Angels </a></li>

    </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#" title="About us">The Stork's Arrival</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="portraiture/adults.php" title="Dults">Adults  </a></li>
    <li><a href="portraiture/seniors.php" title="Seniors">Seniors  </a></li>
    <li><a href="portraiture/infantsandchildren.php" title="InfantsandChildren">Infants and Children  </a></li>
    <li><a href="portraiture/multiples.php" title="Multiples">Mutiples  </a></li>
    <li><a href="portraiture/hisangels.php" title="Hisangels">His Angels </a></li>

    </ul>
    </li>



    <li><a href="#" title="Projects">Triple Braided Cord</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="portraiture/adults.php" title="Adults">Adults  </a></li>
    <li><a href="portraiture/seniors.php" title="Seniors">Seniors  </a></li>
    <li><a href="portraiture/infantsandchildren.php" title="InfantsandChildren">Infants and Children  </a></li>
    <li><a href="portraiture/multiples.php" title="Multiples">Mutiples  </a></li>
    <li><a href="portraiture/hisangels.php" title="Hisangels">His Angels </a></li>

    </ul>
    </li>


    <li><a href="#" title="Contact">Commercial Gallery</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="portraiture/adults.php" title="Dults">Adults  </a></li>
    <li><a href="portraiture/seniors.php" title="Seniors">Seniors  </a></li>
    <li><a href="portraiture/infantsandchildren.php" title="InfantsandChildren">Infants and Children  </a></li>
    <li><a href="portraiture/multiples.php" title="Multiples">Mutiples  </a></li>
    <li><a href="portraiture/hisangels.php" title="Hisangels">His Angels </a></li>

    </ul>
    </li>


    <li><a href="#" title="boudoir">Boudoir</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="portraiture/adults.php" title="Dults">Adults  </a></li>
    <li><a href="portraiture/seniors.php" title="Seniors">Seniors  </a></li>
    <li><a href="portraiture/infantsandchildren.php" title="InfantsandChildren">Infants and Children  </a></li>
    <li><a href="portraiture/multiples.php" title="Multiples">Mutiples  </a></li>
    <li><a href="portraiture/hisangels.php" title="Hisangels">His Angels </a></li>

    </ul>
    </i>



    <li><a href="#" title="hdr">HDR</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="portraiture/adults.php" title="Dults">Adults  </a></li>
    <li><a href="portraiture/seniors.php" title="Seniors">Seniors  </a></li>
    <li><a href="portraiture/infantsandchildren.php" title="InfantsandChildren">Infants and Children  </a></li>
    <li><a href="portraiture/multiples.php" title="Multiples">Mutiples  </a></li>
    <li><a href="portraiture/hisangels.php" title="Hisangels">His Angels </a></li>

    </ul>
    </i>



    <li><a href="#" title="hdr">Fine Art Gallery</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="portraiture/adults.php" title="Dults">Adults  </a></li>
    <li><a href="portraiture/seniors.php" title="Seniors">Seniors  </a></li>
    <li><a href="portraiture/infantsandchildren.php" title="InfantsandChildren">Infants and Children  </a></li>
    <li><a href="portraiture/multiples.php" title="Multiples">Mutiples  </a></li>
    <li><a href="portraiture/hisangels.php" title="Hisangels">His Angels </a></li>

    </ul>
    </i>

</ul>
<!-- /NAVIGATION -->    

</span>
<!-- /CONTAINER -->







</div>

<div align="center"="header-image">
<img src="images/main.jpg" alt="" />
</div>




<div id="content" class="clearfix shadow" >

<div id="sidebar" class="right" >

<div class="right">
<h2>Site Navigation</h2>


<div id="header" class="clearfix shadow">




        <div id="nav" class="clearfix" align="center">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>

            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Default layout</a></li>

            </ul>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="2-columns-left.html">2 columns (left)</a></li>

            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="current" href="2-columns-right.html">2 columns (right)</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="full-width.html">Full width</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>




</div>
</div>


<div id="main" class="left">
<h2>The Inland CSS template</h2>
<p>This is Inland, the first in a new series of HTML/CSS templates from <a href="http://andreasviklund.com/">andreasviklund.com</a>. It is a multi-layout design, and the first andreasviklund.com template to feature an image slider. Inland is made for template users who want a design that catches the attention of the website visitor and it is suitable for both personal websites and blogs, as well as for professional websites for companies and organizations. Like all templates by Andreas Viklund, it keeps the code simple, making the template easy to customize and build upon. To see the different layout options, click the main menu links above...</p>
</div>
</div>

<div id="footer" class="shadow">
<p>&copy; 2012 Your Name | <a href="http://andreasviklund.com/templates/inland-hembygd/">Template design</a> by <a href="http://andreasviklund.com/">andreasviklund.com</a> and <a href="http://allyourbasearebelongtous.se/">Daniel Carlsson</a></p>
</div>
</div>
</li>

</body>

</html>
```

Finally the menu.js javascript

```
// JavaScript Document

// DropDownMenu by Miha Hribar
// http://hribar.info

function addLoadEvent(func) {
    var oldonload = window.onload;
    if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
        window.onload = func;
    } else {
        window.onload = function() {
            oldonload();
            func();
        }
    }
}

function prepareMenu() {
    // first lets make sure the browser understands the DOM methods we will be using
    if (!document.getElementsByTagName) return false;
    if (!document.getElementById) return false;

    // lets make sure the element exists
    if (!document.getElementById("menu")) return false;
    var menu = document.getElementById("menu");

    // for each of the li on the root level check if the element has any children
    // if so append a function that makes the element appear when hovered over
    var root_li = menu.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (var i = 0; i < root_li.length; i++) {
        var li = root_li[i];
        // search for children
        var child_ul = li.getElementsByTagName("ul");
        if (child_ul.length >= 1) {
            // we have children - append hover function to the parent
            li.onmouseover = function () {
                if (!this.getElementsByTagName("ul")) return false;
                var ul = this.getElementsByTagName("ul");
                ul[0].style.display = "block";
                return true;
            }
            li.onmouseout = function () {
                if (!this.getElementsByTagName("ul")) return false;
                var ul = this.getElementsByTagName("ul");
                ul[0].style.display = "none";
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}

addLoadEvent(prepareMenu);
```

I am trying to make both the right side and top menus to be added to each page through include statements.

Comment: I know it is a ton of code. Most of it is for navigation. it wouldn't be such a big deal if it all were in nav.php but is not and that is what I am trying to fix.

Comment: I am sorry that there is so much code, but I didn't think that I could ask my question without it. I am trying to figure how to include a js menu with php.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Include a javascript menu using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266437/include-a-javascript-menu-using-php)

Answer (score 1):

You're including the `nav.php` above the HTML of the page. Put that include statement where you want the navigation to show. Inside `nav.php` you should have just the HTML you want inserted into that spot. It's literally going to take the code in the file, and put it in the place where you have the `include` statement.

Comment: The thing is that I have tried that. I am wondering too if the layers and layers of divs is somehow hiding the navigation bar when I use an include?

Comment: Check the DOM. View source and see what you get.

Comment: At the moment there is just some test code. I am wondering what should go in there to somehow merge the php and javascript?

Comment: Ok, include will take whatever is in the file and insert it wherever you include it. If you want to modularize your navigation, put the navigation HTML in there and include it wherever you want.