# Include a javascript menu using php

Tags: php, javascript

This is my second attempt at this question so please bear with me.

How do you include a JS menu into a php page?

whenever I do a include statement for nav which has html in it, nothing shows up.

index.php has an include statment that should take the code from nav and display it using the menu.js

here is snippet from index

```
    <span id="container" >

        <!-- NAVIGATION -->
        <ul id="menu">

<?php include('nav.php')?>
            </ul>
     </span>
```

and here is nav.php

```
 <li><a href="index.php" title="Portraiture Gallery" class="selected">Portraiture Gallery</a>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="portraiture/adults.php" title="Adults">Adults  </a></li>
            <li><a href="portraiture/seniors.php" title="Seniors">Seniors  </a></li>
            <li><a href="portraiture/infantsandchildren.php" title="InfantsandChildren">Infants and Children  </a></li>
            <li><a href="portraiture/multiples.php" title="Multiples">Mutiples  </a></li>
            <li><a href="portraiture/hisangels.php" title="Hisangels">His Angels </a></li>

            </ul>
            </li>
```

this format is followed because the menu.js is written for that.

menu.js

```
 // JavaScript Document

    // DropDownMenu by Miha Hribar
    // http://hribar.info

    function addLoadEvent(func) {
        var oldonload = window.onload;
        if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
            window.onload = func;
        } else {
            window.onload = function() {
                oldonload();
                func();
            }
        }
    }

    function prepareMenu() {
        // first lets make sure the browser understands the DOM methods we will be using
        if (!document.getElementsByTagName) return false;
        if (!document.getElementById) return false;

        // lets make sure the element exists
        if (!document.getElementById("menu")) return false;
        var menu = document.getElementById("menu");

        // for each of the li on the root level check if the element has any children
        // if so append a function that makes the element appear when hovered over
        var root_li = menu.getElementsByTagName("li");
        for (var i = 0; i < root_li.length; i++) {
            var li = root_li[i];
            // search for children
            var child_ul = li.getElementsByTagName("ul");
            if (child_ul.length >= 1) {
                // we have children - append hover function to the parent
                li.onmouseover = function () {
                    if (!this.getElementsByTagName("ul")) return false;
                    var ul = this.getElementsByTagName("ul");
                    ul[0].style.display = "block";
                    return true;
                }
                li.onmouseout = function () {
                    if (!this.getElementsByTagName("ul")) return false;
                    var ul = this.getElementsByTagName("ul");
                    ul[0].style.display = "none";
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    addLoadEvent(prepareMenu);
```

Comment: What's "JS menu"? Could you show at least some pseudocode of what you're trying to get?

Comment: So, your going to have to provide more information than that. What do you mean by "JS menu"? Maybe showing code for that would help. Also, showing your PHP code would helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked for any error messages that might have been generated by PHP at runtime?

Not all PHP error messages will be shown in the browser (depending on your HTTP configuration) so it's always helpful to check the error.log file that's usually located alongside your access.log file.

Comment: I'm Just using notepad++ so I dont know if it has that.

Comment: Are you executing the php file on the command line or on a web server?

Comment: Most servers will store the access and error log files in the root directory for the site.  If you are uploading your files to a folder named www - public_html - htdocs - etc... you will probably find a folder named logs in the parent directory.

Comment: Hang on!  How are you linking your menu.js file to the index file?  Are you using script tags? <script type="text/javascript" src="menu.js"></script>

Comment: Yeah I used script tags                                          <link href="drop-down-menu.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="menu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13233/discussion-between-kreeseeker-and-danielcraigie)